# How do I sub query data prior to plot

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like this

```
col1 - desc, col2 - value, col3 - count (header)
value1,      descriptor 1, 6
value1,      descriptor 2, 3
value1,      descriptor 3, 1
value2,      descriptor 7, 8
value2,      descriptor 8, 6
value2,      descriptor 9, 2
```

I need to partition the data in such a manner as to use col2 on the x axis with col 3 as the y value, for each unique value in col1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear what kind of plots you are planning to create. But I think the key is to split the data frame based on `col1`. After that, create plot for each separated data frame.

Here is an example. The final output, `p_lst`, contains bar plot for all unique values in `col1` using `col2` as x-axis and `col3` as y-axis. Notice that I also added `col1` in the title for each plot.

```
# Load package
library(ggplot2)

# Create example data frame
dt <- read.csv(text = "col1 - desc, col2 - value, col3 - count (header)
value1,      descriptor 1, 6
value1,      descriptor 2, 3
value1,      descriptor 3, 1
value2,      descriptor 7, 8
value2,      descriptor 8, 6
value2,      descriptor 9, 2",
               header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Rename dt
colnames(dt) <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")

# Split dt based on col1, save results to lst
lst <- split(dt, dt$col1)

# Create a function to produce bar plot
bar_fun <- function(dt){
  p <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = col2, y = col3)) +
    geom_col() +
    ggtitle(as.character(unique(dt$col1)))

  return(p)
}

# Plot all data frames in lst
p_lst <- lapply(lst, bar_fun)

# You can access individual plot by index or name
p_lst[[1]]
p_lst$value2
```

Comment: Hi - you correctly surmised that I was going to do a bar plot.  Thanks a bunch for the example!.  Concise and exactly what I was needing.  Adding it to my knowledge toolkit.